# Weird .NET Stored Proc Behavior

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlcommand

I have a stored procedure that I am calling via a SqlCommand in .NET.  Its pretty out of the box implementation and I have all kinds of code that access other stored procedures that seem to work fine.  However, for some reason I keep getting an error from the stored procedure because it thinks one of the parameters being passed in is NULL even though I'm passing it a value.  I've run a trace on the database while executing the code and I can see the value being passed so I'm not sure where to go from here. Hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm missing.  Here's the .NET code:

```
    private void InsertAuditRecord(int recipientId, EventType eventType, string jsonProperties)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Ual__InsUalLog", cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventTimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", _accountId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", this.SystemLogin);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserNameEffective", this.SystemLogin);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionId", this.SessionId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UalUserActivityLogEventTypeId", (int)eventType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityTitle", AUDIT_ENTITYTITLE_RECIPIENT);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityId", recipientId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Properties", jsonProperties);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UalUserActivityLogId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@UalUserActivityLogId"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the out put I'm getting from the trace I'm running on the database when this code is executed:

```
 declare @p12 int
 set @p12=NULL
 exec sp_executesql N'usp_Ual__InsUalLog',N'@EventTimeStamp datetime,@AccountId int,@UserName nvarchar(5),@UserNameEffective nvarchar(5),@SessionId int,@UalUserActivityLogEventTypeId int,@EntityTitle nvarchar(12),@EntityId int,@Properties nvarchar(143),@UalUserActivityLogId int output',@EventTimeStamp='2014-08-25 09:35:41.613',@AccountId=10010,@UserName=N'hydra',@UserNameEffective=N'hydra',@SessionId=1957,@UalUserActivityLogEventTypeId=22,@EntityTitle=N'recipient_id',@EntityId=79,@Properties=N'{"ClientUniqueRecipientId":"opt_sms_6174358864","ContactPointAddress":"6174358864","GroupId":"4","ShortCode":"12345","EventCode":"sam-weather"}',@UalUserActivityLogId=@p12 output
 select @p12
```

The stored procedure thinks the value of @AccountId is NULL even though there is a value being passed into the trace.  Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the data type for every parameter to see if that has an effect?

Comment: Are the parameters added in the order they are defined in the stored procedure? As a matter of clarity you may want to declaritively define the parameters like:

`usp_Ual__InsUalLog @EventTimeStamp = @EventTimeStamp, @AccountId = @AccountId, ...`

Comment: Yeah - they are added in the order they are defined. I haven't tried explicitly specifying the value but I always use .AddWithValue() without an issue.  But I'll try specifying the value for that parameter and seeing if it helps.

Comment: Just tried it by specifying the datatype - no luck. It still thinks the @AccountId value is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  Because I was specifying an output parameter, I needed to set the CommandType on the SqlCommand to Stored Procedure:

```
    private void InsertAuditRecord(int recipientId, EventType eventType, string jsonProperties)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Ual__InsUalLog"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventTimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", _accountId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", this.SystemLogin);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserNameEffective", this.SystemLogin);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionId", this.SessionId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UalUserActivityLogEventTypeId", (int)eventType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityTitle", AUDIT_ENTITYTITLE_RECIPIENT);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityId", recipientId.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Properties", jsonProperties);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UalUserActivityLogId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
                { 
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                });

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Once I did this, the code executed fine.  *sigh* It's always the little things.